# Skobbler background mode without SKTNavigationManager

Tags: ios, swift, skmaps

I'm developing an IOS app in swift language with the Skobbler navigation SDK. 
I try to allow the user to use navigation while in background mode (IPhone locked).

I have question stated below :

**1) Is it possible to do so without using the SDKTools and the SKTNavigationManager ? We only use SKMaps.frameworks functions.**

With this configuration, I can't use the allowBackgroundNavigation
property of SKTNavigationConfiguration like in the demo.

I set
`SKPositionerService.sharedInstance().worksInBackground  = true`

and allowed the "location Update in BackgroundMode" to the info.plist. Unfortunately the updateCurrentLocation doesn't triggered in background and navigation doesn't works neither.

**Thank you very much in advance :-) !!**

---

P.S. : I succeeded to run a short code in background with the official library CCLocationManager. So my app seems correctly configured...

Comment: thanks IPR for editing my question :-)

Comment: Have you set "worksInBackground" on SKPositionerService before startLocationUpdate?

Comment: Hi SylviA. I have the same problem. Check my 'answer' for more code.

Comment: Yes worksInBackground is set before, just as Guido's code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hotfix for this issue can be downloaded from here:

ObjC: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ruk6at2fju0rdd7/SKMaps_2_5_1.zip?dl=0

Swift: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lgbdherhqzudy2a/SKMapsSwift_2_5_1.zip?dl=0

Comment: GREAT ! It seems to be okay now ! I've updated the SKMaps.framework with the hotfix one and I now have my updatedCurrentLocation triggered.
Thanks a lot to SylviA and the dev team ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry..this is not an answer, but a "Same Problem". `updatedCurrentLocation` is not called when the app is in the background.
Thought I add some more code to give more info and perhaps find the cause:

My code:

```
SKPositionerService.sharedInstance().delegate = self
SKPositionerService.sharedInstance().worksInBackground = true
SKPositionerService.sharedInstance().automaticLocationUpdatePause = false
SKPositionerService.sharedInstance().startLocationUpdate()
```

Also tried putting `SKPositionerService.sharedInstance().startLocationUpdate()` as first line. No luck.

When I run a CLLocationManager alongside the SKPositionerService like so:

```
locManager = CLLocationManager()
locManager.desiredAccuracy = 10000
locManager.distanceFilter = 10000
locManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
locManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
locManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

`updatedCurrentLocation` IS being called while in background.

I used this when I was running 2.5.0 as that version was not yet iOS9 ready, but I thought that 2.5.1 would be. This of course is a horrible workaround as a 2nd locationmanager eats battery.

Could it be that, in the SKPositionerService implementation, you are not setting  `CLLocationManager().allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates` to true when `SKPositionerService.sharedInstance().worksInBackground` is set to true?

btw I'm running the 2.5.1 hot fix posted [here](http://forum.skobbler.com/showthread.php/7563-Latest-2-5-1-builds).

btw2: This can not be tested in the simulator. The simulator will call `updatedCurrentLocation` even when the app is 'backgrounded'. I'm guessing because the simulator doesn't really have a 'background' mode.

btw3: I would be very surprised if background mode works for the SDKTools Navigation Manager... with this 2.5.1. hot fix)

Comment: I've reported it to our development team

Comment: If it's indeed what I'm suspecting/suggesting another 'hotfix' would be nice. 

Comment: Hi guido ! Thanks for your additionnal info, I have the exact same code ! And CLLocationManager works as well. 

Thank you SylviA for your report, we're waiting for your news as soon as possible please :) !!